State Managment Of Subset Of Pages - Flutter
I have, for example, 3 pages: A, B, and C in my Flutter app. These are some pages in my app that I use to get data from the user and then upload it. So on page A I get some data, then I navigate to page B to get some more data, and in the end, the app navigates to page C, where I upload that data. Now I need to pass my model that stores the data between these pages. So that when a user fills out that data on page A and then goes to page B and back to page A and again to page B, I can recall the data and recreate the old state on page B.
I have tried to do this with a provider that I create when entering page A, but except for some errors, I didn't get far. Is provider even a good idea for this. The provider wouldn't probably be useful anyway because the state needs to reset every time I enter page A from the other app pages, but when navigating between pages A and B the state has to persist.
Thank you!
